# Journey has completely reset its own save data for no reason, how can I get it back?

Tags: technical-issues, epic-games-launcher, journey

I've just recently gotten the white robes in the game and have completed the game numerous times already beforehand. This morning I was playing around with the white robes, and then left the game.

After getting back into the game all save data was gone, this includes all progress on collecting each glowing glyph, meaning the white cloths were gone and the marking on my normal red cloak were gone (after multiple playthroughs it adds more detail to the cloak, this is now completely reset too). It's as if I've just installed the game for the first time, yet I didn't uninstall it or do anything to it. I'm stumped in figuring out how to get the save data back - if that's even possible.

I'm on PC bootcamp using Epic Games.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally select "New Journey"?

Comment: This doesn't reset everything, all the glowing sigils next to where the white robes were are gone. They are saved after everytime you collect one so this can't be it. Also The markings on my cloak as I said above disappeared (they collate over the course of the game and for some reason they're completely gone). Also when I went back to the game before any of this happened I had just arrived in the bridge area when I quit the game. When I brought up the game again it wouldn't let me 'continue' just 'start'. I think it might be just my computer doing something funny and misplacing the save data.